# calculating date specific correlation in r (leading to a potential time series)

Tags: r, date, time-series, subset, correlation

I have a dataset that looks somewhat like this (the actual dataset is ~150000 lines with additional columns of fluff information such as company name, etc.):

```
Date         return1   return2   rank
01/31/2008   0.05434   0.23413   3
01/31/2008   0.03423   0.43423   4
01/31/2008   0.65277   0.23423   1
01/31/2008   0.02342   0.47234   4
02/31/2008   0.01463   0.01231   4
02/31/2008   0.13456   0.52552   2
02/31/2008   0.34534   0.36663   1
02/31/2008   0.00324   0.56463   3
...
12/31/2015   0.21234   0.02333   2
12/31/2015   0.07245   0.87234   1
12/31/2015   0.47282   0.12998   1
12/31/2015   0.99022   0.03445   2
```

Basically I need to caculate the date-specific correlation between `return1` and `rank` (so the corr. on 01/31/2008, 02/31/2008, and so on). I know I can split the data using the `split()` function but I am unsure as to how to get the date-specific correlation. The real data has about 260 entries per date and around 68 dates, so manually subsetting the original table and performing calculations is time consuming but more importantly more susceptible to error.

My ultimate goal is to create a time series of the correlations on different dates.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This `dplyr` and `tidyr` cheat sheet has everything you need and presents it in a clear and organized fashion: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: fantastic thank you so much. fyi using the suggested sheet I found the answer to be: `correlations<-as.data.frame(merged_data%>%group_by(Date)%>%summarise(cor(X1.Mo..Forward.Returns,`Team Rank`)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem earlier, except I wasn't calculating correlation. What I would do is

```
a %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Correlation = cor(return1, rank))
```

And this will provide, for each date, a correlation value between `return1` and `rank`. Don't forget that you can specify what kind of correlation you would like (e.g. Spearman).